# Penalty when same token matches in two different field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am working through a scenario where in I am using function scoring to provide scores based on match. So if we search for multiple tokens based on the function scoring we provide scores. We have an instance in which if we are searching for a 3 token text "Mathew Perry Hernandez", one function score searches through first_name field and another function score searches through last_name. If lets say in both search the matched keyword is same i.e Hernandez then do a penalty on the total score. 
Can we achieve this in Elasticsearch query or need to handle this at the processing end once I have all the results  ?
Any ideas or suggestion are most welcome.

Sample document :-

```
{
  "first_name": "HERNANDEZ Socorro Elizabeth",
  "last_name": "Hernandez"
}
```

Query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "dis_max": {
            "queries": [
              {
                "function_score": {
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "minimum_should_match": 1,
                      "should": [
                        {
                          "dis_max": {
                            "queries": [
                              {
                                "function_score": {
                                  "score_mode": "max",
                                  "boost_mode": "replace",
                                  "query": {
                                    "multi_match": {
                                      "query": "Socorro Elizabeth HERNANDEZ",
                                      "fields": [
                                        "first_name_idx_search",
                                        "first_alt_idx_search",
                                        "first_name_idx_search.keyword",
                                        "first_alt_idx_search.keyword"
                                      ],
                                      "operator": "or",
                                      "fuzziness": 2
                                    }
                                  },
                                  "functions": [
                                    {
                                      "filter": {
                                        "multi_match": {
                                          "query": "Socorro Elizabeth HERNANDEZ",
                                          "fields": [
                                            "first_name_idx_search",
                                            "first_alt_idx_search",
                                            "first_name_idx_search.keyword",
                                            "first_alt_idx_search.keyword"
                                          ],
                                          "fuzziness": 0
                                        }
                                      },
                                      "weight": 30
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "dis_max": {
                            "queries": [
                              {
                                "function_score": {
                                  "score_mode": "max",
                                  "boost_mode": "replace",
                                  "query": {
                                    "multi_match": {
                                      "query": "Socorro Elizabeth HERNANDEZ",
                                      "fields": [
                                        "last_name_idx_search",
                                        "last_alt_idx_search",
                                        "last_name_idx_search.keyword",
                                        "last_alt_idx_search.keyword"
                                      ],
                                      "operator": "or",
                                      "fuzziness": 2
                                    }
                                  },
                                  "functions": [
                                    {
                                      "filter": {
                                        "multi_match": {
                                          "query": "Socorro Elizabeth HERNANDEZ",
                                          "fields": [
                                            "last_name_idx_search",
                                            "last_alt_idx_search",
                                            "last_name_idx_search.keyword",
                                            "last_alt_idx_search.keyword"
                                          ],
                                          "fuzziness": 0
                                        }
                                      },
                                      "weight": 70
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "functions": [
                    {
                      "script_score": {
                        "script": {
                          "inline": "Math.min(100, _score)"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If I understand well, you want to avoid that malformed document like : 

    {
        firstName: "Mathew Perry Hernandez",
        lastName: "Mathew Perry Hernandez"
    } 

to be over ranked on "hernandez" search. Is that right ? Coud you show us the request you are currently using ? And maibe provide us with multiple exemple of document in which you want to decrease the natural score ?

Comment: @PierreMallet I have edited the question with my query and one sample case.In the above case if you see HERNANDEZ is present in both first and last name and because of same token we have a match and score is 100. If by any way I will be able to eliminate the duplicate match or assign a penalty(negative boosting) when this kind of scenario happens my case helps.

Comment: Why don't you just use a dismax query to wrap you queries on first_name and last_name? Then the score for matching on the name would only be 70 or 30. No score added for a match in first_name if already matched in last_name.

Comment: yeah that was my initial though but then I will be loosing in the scenario where in 
                   {
                            "first_name": "Socorro Elizabeth",
                            "last_name": "Hernandez"
                    }
In this case I should be getting a score of 100, because I have all the tokens matched. But with the proposed idea we will get only 70.